# Mongodb error show line number and filename

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm getting errors like this after upgrading from mongodb node native driver 2.x to 3.x

`Third parameter to find() must be a callback or undefined`

I know what to do I just need to know what file this is in. How do I config the driver to show file / line when the error should appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this article - http://thecodebarbarian.com/using-monogram-to-upgrade-from-mongodb-node-driver-2-to-3.html

What you need to do is to add middleware that will throw exception and stacktrace

```js
db.collection('Test').pre(/^(find|findOne)$/, action => {
  const opts = action.params[1];
  const allowedOptions = ['projection', 'sort', 'skip', 'limit', 'hint'];
  if (opts != null &&
      Object.keys(opts).find(option => !allowedOptions.includes(option))) {
    throw new Error('MongoDB driver 3.x does not allow passing projection ' +
      'as 2nd arg to find(). Use `projection` instead. Got ' +
      require('util').inspect(opts));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, is there no way to add middleware to the node native driver and you need to adopt monogram? Is it api compatible with node native such that I only need to replace the startup? I'm having a hard time getting their api to play nicely with my existing code.